# Reusable Button with Image

Tags: react-native

So i'm new to react native and javascript, and i want to make a reusable button with image and i found this code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const ImgButtons = ({ onPress, img }) => {

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    <Image
      source={require(img)}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export { ImgButtons };
```

and i call the component

```js
 <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <ImgButtons
           img={require('../assets/btn-reg-1.jpg')}/>
  </View>
```

i got an error say  Error: component/ImgButtons.js:Invalid call at line 9: require(img)

can somebody help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you custom component I edited Image source check below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const ImgButtons = ({ onPress, img }) => {

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    <Image
      source={img}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export { ImgButtons };
```

Then you have to pass some method onPress

```
<View style={styles.innerContainer}>
    <ImgButtons
       img={require('../assets/btn-reg-1.jpg')}
       onPress={()=>console.log('Action')}
    />
</View>
```